# How do I include excluded rows from JOINS where the join column's value is 0?

Tags: mysql, join

In one of my tables I have a column named `dl_id` which may contain an ID or 0.  (Another column is `type` which is enum('cat', 'dl'); `dl_id` is always 0 when `type` = 'cat'.)

I want to do JOIN on this column, so I can pull the dl_id's title from a different table.  However when I do the JOIN, the rows where `dl_id` = 0 are removed from the results presumably because '0' isn't an ID in that other table.

Is there any way to include these rows and just list their values as NULL instead of excluding them from the results (i.e. is there a way to override the default behavior)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join)

A simple to understand [tutorial](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqljoin/mysql-outer-join.shtml)

Comment: This is a good place to look too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/outer-join-simplification.html